# Editing vector tiles?

Tags: javascript, mapnik, vector-tiles

I'd like to create a web service where the user can edit some basic information of vector tiles. For example change the category of a street category from 5 to other value (4,3,2,1).

I'm not so interested in editing the geometry.

Would this be possible with mapnik or other tile server? Can you give some advice where to start?

- How to include metadata (i.e. street category) in the tiles?
- Which javascript libraries can be used to edit such data?

Comment: Is the aim to send edited data back to central database, or to just edit the local copy ?

Comment: I would like to send the data back to the server database